# What's the meaning of "audit: backlog limit exceeded"

Tags: server, 18.04, log

I have a Ubuntu Server machine running Docker containers. I have some hard drives mounted for the Docker machines to use (mainly media storage)

I installed Ubuntu Server with all defaults settings.
I have on the screen many logs appearing:

> [59.959145] audit: backlog limit exceeded

The lines are appearing randomly, and I have no idea what it means...

Answer (score 5):

I believe this occurs when kernel kauditd thread is not being able to service the audit records fast enough and a backlog occurs. The default audit backlog is 64 audit buffers, so it may help if these are increased.  This can be set to be larger using the  kernel parameter "audit_backlog_limit".

For example, edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `audit_backlog_limit=256` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` setting and `run sudo update-grub` to set this to 256 buffers.